# This site cannot be reached error while authorizing Org in VSCode

Tags: vs-code

I was trying to authorize the Org in the VSCode.

It is taking me to a page on localhost on port 1717.

I am getting an error like below:

[image]

When I checked the URL. It was like this:

[image]

How to get over this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the message in the URL was saying **this app is blocked by admin**.

So the app is needed to be unblocked

When checked in the Org, the Connected app for **Salesforce CLI** was not installed.

In Salesforce Classic, I went to Setup->Manage Apps->Connected Apps OAuth Usage.

Clicked on the install button in front of Salesforce CLI.

After installing, Clicked on the **Unblock** to enable the connectivity.

Comment: You don't need to manually install the Salesforce CLI Connected App. All you need to do is open up your local network.